# How to make a Histogram of the frequency of Dates in Power BI

Tags: plot, powerbi, histogram

I am trying to make a histogram from a column of dates. All I want to know is the frequency of the dates in each bucket. For some reason this works fine for regular numbers, but Power BI cannot handle it with dates. Any ideas?
I have tried using a group but that did not solve it either.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Turns out Power BI cannot use dates very well and I needed to convert those values to datevalues.
Very simple solution to the issue, but I hope they fix this some day...